# Sass use of @at-root

Tags: html, css, sass

How to properly declare the sass statement to produce the output css in comment ?

```
.formModal{
    .modal-body{
        .inputTextWrap{

            /*
            .modal-body > .inputTextWrap:first-child {
                background:violet;
            }
            */

        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.formModal{
    .modal-body{
        .inputTextWrap{
          @at-root .modal-body > .inputTextWrap:first-child{
         background: violet; //Remember you need a space after the:
          };
        }
    } 
}
```

You can check stuff like this on sassmeister